# Creating a new Starter Site

Tags: c1-cms

I'm completely new to Composite C1 and fairly new to CMS's in general. According to the documentation, the **Tiny Cph Starter Site** template was installed when I installed Composite C1.  It sounds like what I want to use, but how do I create a new website project using that template?  I'm not finding any instructions on how to get started with this.

Comment: Has your site been initialised yet ? So you are past this step: http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Guide/Installation-and-Setup

Comment: Just to complete the comment above - take a look at the get started guide. It's a pretty neat guide that lines out all the bits and bobs that need to be done once logged in as admin. http://users.composite.net/Getting-Started

Comment: Ahh, I see what happened. I installed it a while ago, set it aside and now I'm going back. Didn't realize this was part of the install.